# How to insert data in a date column from a different table with the oldest date using postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables `trainings` and `training_instances`. Please see the schema below:

trainings table:

```
column_name   data_type     is_nullable. foreign_key

id            uuid          NO           NULL
day           int4          NO           NULL
start_time    time(0)       NO           NULL
end_time      time(0)       NO           NULL
team_id       uuid          YES          public.teams(id)
inserted_at   timestamp(0)  NO           NULL
updated_at    timestamp(0)  NO           NULL
```

Note that trainings table does not have a date or start_date column yet. The column named `day` is the day of the week. One training_id can have multiple training instances.

training_instances table:

```
column_name   data_type     is_nullable. foreign_key
id            uuid          NO           NULL
date          date          NO           NULL
start_time    time(0)       NO           NULL
end_time      time(0)       NO           NULL
team_size     int4          YES          NULL
training_id   uuid          YES          public.trainings(id)
team_id       uuid          YES          public.teams(id)
inserted_at   timestamp(0)  NO           NULL
updated_at    timestamp(0)  NO           NULL
```

I am trying to create a new column named `start_date` in the `trainings` table and then insert the data here for existing trainings. I want to insert for every training the oldest `date` for its corresponding training instance in this new `start_date` column.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Is the value of `start_date` *always* going to be the oldest `date` for the corresponding training instances? Or is that just an initial value but may change?

Comment: This is only to populate the new `start_date` column for existing trainings. We are currently developing a new feature using which the user can directly insert the `start_date` whenever he/she creates a new training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, create the column using

```
alter table public.trainings add "start_date" date null;
```

Then, try to execute this query

```
update trainings 
  set start_date = (select min(ti.date) from training_instances ti where 
    trainings.team_id = ti.team_id and 
    trainings.id = ti.training_id)
```

Comment: your query works for me✅
Thanks!